# How to get the position of the second occurrence?

Tags: javascript, arrays, position, indexof

Let's say I have this array:

```
var a = [1,2,99,3,4,99,5];
```

I would like to get the position of the second `99`, something like:

```
a.indexOf(99, 2) // --> 5
```

However the second argument in `indexOf` just tells where to start the search. Is there any built in functions to make this? If not how would you do it?

Thanks!

Comment: `a.indexOf(99, a.indexOf(99)+1)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's only `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf`. You could loop over it:

```
var a = [1,2,99,3,4,99,5];
var matches = []
for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
    if (a[i] == 99) {
        matches.push(i)
    }
}
console.log(matches); // [2, 5]
```

If you always want the second occurrence Jan's method is also good:

```
a.indexOf(99, a.indexOf(99) + 1)
```

The `indexOf` call on the right finds the first occurrence, `+1` then limits the search to the elements that follow it.

Comment: actually your answer is right, however I just realized that I'm looking for something else http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480345/regex-how-to-get-the-nth-occurrence-in-a-string

Comment: @Adam: You could use my answer together with `strpos` insead of `indexOf`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: @Adam: Oops... then just keep using `indexOf` ;) Sorry, got confused for a second. My solution works for strings as well (as long as you don't want to consider word boundaries).  Just sayin' :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no built in function, but you can easily create your own, by iteratively applying `indexOf`:

```
function indexOfOccurrence(haystack, needle, occurrence) {
    var counter = 0;
    var index = -1;
    do {
        index = haystack.indexOf(needle, index + 1);
    }
    while (index !== -1 && (++counter < occurrence));
    return index;
}

// Usage
var index = indexOfOccurrence(a, 99, 2);
```

But [Matt's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14479730/218196) might be more useful.