# Finding second occurrence of a substring in a string in Java

Tags: java, string, substring, indexof

We are given a string, say, `"itiswhatitis"` and a substring, say, `"is"`.
I need to find the index of `'i'` when the string `"is"` occurs a second time in the original string.

`String.indexOf("is")` will return 2 in this case. I want the output to be 10 in this case.

Answer (score 221, accepted):

Use overloaded version of [`indexOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-int-), which takes the starting index  (fromIndex) as 2nd parameter:

```
str.indexOf("is", str.indexOf("is") + 1);
```

Comment: This is ingenious.

Answer (score 60):

I am using: 
[Apache Commons Lang: StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#ordinalIndexOf(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int))

```
StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf("Java Language", "a", 2)
```

Comment: Nice and clear, thanks!

Answer (score 38):

```
int first = string.indexOf("is");
int second = string.indexOf("is", first + 1);
```

This overload starts looking for the substring from the given index.

Comment: what if the occurence is more than twice?

Comment: Then nothing special happens, it will still take the second occurence.

Comment: what about the index of third occurence!

Comment: What about it? The question was to find the second occurence.

Comment: i mean what if 10 occcurences are there in the string

Comment: @PravatPanda: I guess you want to know how to get the third occurence? Then you could just continue the code in Jeroen's answer and add a third `string.indexOf("is", second + 1);` although it would probably be better to make a method that returns the Nth indexOf

Comment: @JuhaUntinen recursion??

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function to return array of occurrence positions, Java has String.regionMatches function which is quite handy

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> occurrencesPos(String str, String substr) {
    final boolean ignoreCase = true;
    int substrLength = substr.length();
    int strLength = str.length();

    ArrayList<Integer> occurrenceArr = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i = 0; i < strLength - substrLength + 1; i++) {
        if(str.regionMatches(ignoreCase, i, substr, 0, substrLength))  {
            occurrenceArr.add(i);
        }
    }
    return occurrenceArr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I'm not late to the party.. Here is my answer. I like using Pattern/Matcher because it uses regex which should be more efficient. Yet, I think this answer could be enhanced:

```
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("is").matcher("I think there is a smarter solution, isn't there?");
    int numOfOcurrences = 2;
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfOcurrences; i++) matcher.find();
    System.out.println("Index: " + matcher.start());
```

Comment: Nice solution, I found. Thank you Hasnaa!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a good party... I'm in:

```
public static int nthIndexOf(String str, String subStr, int count) {
    int ind = -1;
    while(count > 0) {
        ind = str.indexOf(subStr, ind + 1);
        if(ind == -1) return -1;
        count--;
    }
    return ind;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Anyone who is looking for [Nth occurance of string](https://www.tutorialkart.com/java/get-the-index-of-nth-occurrence-of-a-substring-in-a-string-using-java/)

```
    public class NthOccuranceExample {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1 = "helloworld good morning good evening good night";
        String str2 = "ing";
        int n = 2;
    
        int index = nthOccurrence(str1, str2, n);
        System.out.println("index of str2 in str1 at occurrence "+ n +" = "+ index);
    }
    
    public static int nthOccurrence(String str1, String str2, int n) {
    
        String tempStr = str1;
        int tempIndex = -1;
        int finalIndex = 0;
        for(int occurrence = 0; occurrence < n ; ++occurrence){
            tempIndex = tempStr.indexOf(str2);
            if(tempIndex==-1){
                finalIndex = 0;
                break;
            }
            tempStr = tempStr.substring(++tempIndex);
            finalIndex+=tempIndex;
        }
        return --finalIndex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get any occurrence of a substring in a string with a recursive method like this without any libraries:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String word = "unrestfulness";
        String[] temp = new String[word.length()];
        for (char c : word.toCharArray()) {
            int count = (int) Arrays.stream(temp).filter(e -> e != null && e.contains(String.valueOf(c))).count();
            int index = getIndex(word, String.valueOf(c), count);
            System.out.println(c + " " + count + " " + index);
            temp[index] = String.valueOf(c);
        }
    
        System.out.println("result -> " + Arrays.toString(temp));
    }
    
    public static int getIndex(String word, String letter, int count) {
        return count == 0 ? word.indexOf(letter) : word.indexOf(letter, getIndex(word, letter, count - 1) + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think a loop can be used.

```
1 - check if the last index of substring is not the end of the main string.
2 - take a new substring from the last index of the substring to the last index of the main string and check if it contains the search string
3 - repeat the steps in a loop
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to find index for more than 2 occurrence:

```
public static int ordinalIndexOf(String fullText,String subText,int pos){

    if(fullText.contains(subText)){
        if(pos <= 1){
            return fullText.indexOf(subText);
        }else{
            --pos;
            return fullText.indexOf(subText, ( ordinalIndexOf(fullText,subText,pos) + 1) );
        }
    }else{
        return -1;
    }

}
```