# Javascript function for RSS JSON Display not getting the right profile picture

Tags: javascript, json, rss

I wanted to get the profile photos per post of this site (https://medium.com/@femalefounderssg) using this javascript function but I am not getting the right photo. Please guide me in changing my code for me to get the appropriate photo. Thank you. Here is the code.

```
$(function () {
var $content = $('#jsonContent');
var data = {
    rss_url: 'https://medium.com/feed/@femalefounderssg'
};
$.get('https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json', data, function (response) {
    if (response.status == 'ok') {
        var output = '';
        $.each(response.items, function (k, item) {
            var visibleSm;
            if(k < 3){
                visibleSm = '';
             } else {
                 visibleSm = ' visible-sm';
             }
            output += '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4' + visibleSm + '">';
            output += '<div class="blog-post"><header>';
            output += '<h4 class="date">' + $.format.date(item.pubDate, "dd<br>MMM") + "</h4>";
            var tagIndex = item.description.indexOf('<img'); // Find where the img tag starts
            var srcIndex = item.description.substring(tagIndex).indexOf('src=') + tagIndex; // Find where the src attribute starts
            var srcStart = srcIndex + 5; // Find where the actual image URL starts; 5 for the length of 'src="'
            var srcEnd = item.description.substring(srcStart).indexOf('"') + srcStart; // Find where the URL ends
            var src = item.description.substring(srcStart, srcEnd); // Extract just the URL
            output += '<div class="blog-element"><img class="img-responsive" src="' + src + '" width="360px" height="240px"></div></header>';
            output += '<div class="blog-content"><h4><a href="'+ item.link + '">' + item.title + '</a></h4>';
            output += '<div class="post-meta"><span>By ' + item.author + '</span></div>';
            var yourString = item.description.replace(/<img[^>]*>/g,""); //replace with your string.
            var maxLength = 120 // maximum number of characters to extract
            //trim the string to the maximum length
            var trimmedString = yourString.substr(0, maxLength);
            //re-trim if we are in the middle of a word
            trimmedString = trimmedString.substr(0, Math.min(trimmedString.length, trimmedString.lastIndexOf(" ")))
            output += '<p>' + trimmedString + '...</p>';
            output += '</div></div></div>';
            return k < 3;
        });
        $content.html(output);
    }
  });
});
```

Current Profile Output:

[image]

Desired Profile Output:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the wrong image because the first result you get when searching for `<img` index is the author's image.

You need to skip the first result and get the second one:

[Finding second occurrence of a substring in a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035893/finding-second-occurrence-of-a-substring-in-a-string-in-java) [it's Java, but the concept remains]

```
var tagIndex = item.description.indexOf('<img', item.description.indexOf('<img') + 1);
```

[`String#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) supports a second argument as "fromIndex". 
By adding 1 to the index of the first result we make sure that the first `<img` will not match, and instead the second `<img` will.

---

Simplified JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yuriy636/03n1hffh/