# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to get string from long string

Tags: java, android, string, substring

I tried to get string from long string which is Firebase URL

```
"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/No-manworld-3577.appspot.com/o/Contacts%2F1510361061636_Julien_Vcf?alt=media&token=c0bff20d-d115-4fef-b58c-4c7ffaef4296"
```

Now if you notice there is under score before and after name **Julien** in above string. I am trying to get that name but i am getting

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
```

Here is my piece of code

```
String s="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/No-manworld-3577.appspot.com/o/Contacts%2F1510361061636_Julien_Vcf?alt=media&token=c0bff20d-d115-4fef-b58c-4c7ffaef4296";

        String newName=s.substring(s.indexOf("_")+1, s.indexOf("_"));
        System.out.println(newName);
```

Comment: When using substring, the first number has to be smaller than the second one. In your case, you are calling substring with `x + 1` and `x`. `x + 1 > x` thus substring fails. `-- EDIT` x being `s.indexOf("_")`

Comment: @nicovank Can you elaborate your comment as answer

Comment: `s.indexOf("_")` is 99. You are basically calling `s.substring(99 + 1, 99)`, whereas the second argument of substring has to be bigger than the first one.

Comment: I changed `(s.indexOf("_"), s.indexOf("_")+1)` but now result is blank. How can i get name Julien as string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in my comment, when using substring, the first number has to be smaller than the second one.

In your case, you are calling substring with `x + 1` and `x`. `x + 1` > `x` thus substring fails, with `x` being `s.indexOf("_")`.

I understand that you are trying to get the [second `indexOf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035893/finding-second-occurrence-of-a-substring-in-a-string-in-java) of `_`.

Here is code that would in your case yield `Julien`:

```
String s = "...";

int start = s.indexOf("_") + 1;
int end = s.indexOf("_", start);

// name will hold the content of s between the first two `_`s, assuming they exist.
String name = s.substring(start, end);
```

Comment: If you see lot of questions and answers related to this issue (Same as i tried) but its not work in my case. This thing is lil tricky and might be helpful for others too like me. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

If requirements are not clear on which 2 `_` to select then here is Java 8 Stream way of doing it ..

```
public class Check {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/No-manworld-3577.appspot.com/o/Contacts%2F1510361061636_Julien_Vcf?alt=media&token=c0bff20d-d115-4fef-b58c-4c7ffaef4296";
        long count = s.chars().filter(ch -> ch == '_').count();
        if (count == 2) {
            System.out.println(s.substring(s.indexOf('_') + 1, s.lastIndexOf('_')));
        } else {
            System.out.println("More than 2 underscores");
        }
    }
}
```

**Why your code didn't work?**

Let assume `s.indexOf("_")` gets some positive number say `10` then below translates to ...

```
String newName=s.substring(s.indexOf("_")+1, s.indexOf("_"));

String newName=s.substring(11, 10);
```

This will give `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` as `endIndex < beginIndex` for `subString` method.