# Split string on Nth occurrence of char

Tags: c#, split

I have this a lot of strings like this:

```
29/10/2018 14:50:09402325 671
```

I want to split these string so they are like this:

`29/10/2018 14:50`

`09402325 671`

These will then be added to a data set and analysed later.

The issue I am having is if I use this code:

```
 string[] words = emaildata.Split(':');
```

it splits them twice; I only want to split it once on the second occurrence of the :.

How can I do that?

Comment: Use [`LastIndexOf(':')`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_LastIndexOf_System_Char_) followed by `Substring()`s

Comment: Just determine the 2nd index https://stackoverflow.com/a/19035944/1315444

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `LastIndexOf()` and some subsequent `Substring()` calls:

```
string input = "29/10/2018 14:50:09402325 671";

int index = input.LastIndexOf(':');

string firstPart = input.Substring(0, index);
string secondPart = input.Substring(index + 1);
```

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4zboBA)

However, another thing to ask yourself is if you even need to make it more complicated than it needs to be.  It looks like this data will always be of a the same length *until* that second `:` instance right?  Why not just split at a known index (i.e not finding the `:` first):

```
string firstPart = input.Substring(0, 16);
string secondPart = input.Substring(17);
```

Comment: Great answer, and very valid point about the date time always being the same length, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you can reverse the string, then call the regular split method asking for a single result, and then reverse back the two results

Answer (score 0):

and with a regex : https://dotnetfiddle.net/Nfiwmv

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program  {
    public static void Main() {
        string input = "29/10/2018 14:50:09402325 671";
        Regex rx = new Regex(@"(.*):([^:]+)",
            RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(input);
        if ( matches.Count >= 1 ) {
            var m = matches[0].Groups;
            Console.WriteLine(m[1]);
            Console.WriteLine(m[2]);        
        }
    }
}
```