# Filename issue when downloading file

Tags: java, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

In edge, I am accessing a JSP page that returns me a file. It works perfectly in chrome but in Edge and Internet explorer I am getting the mime type appended to the filename.

This is the response header:

[image]

Edge asked me to save the file and the filename is

> persistenceIDs.xlsx.vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to prevent its happening, or are you content just to deal with it if it does (for instance if you find more than 2 dots, take a substring from 0 to the position of the second dot)?

Comment: in Chrome, the file is downloaded as "persistenceIDs.xlsx" as it should be but not in Edge or IE. I'd like to understand why it's not using the filename specified in the header?

Comment: If you try to provide any sample code to produce the issue than we can try to make a test and try to find any possible solution for the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an example of mime sniffing, which is odd given that you have nosniff in your header (but from what I am reading online, sometimes these browsers are stubborn). There is stuff out there about how to reset your browser or edit the registry, but I wrote a little function to manage the result instead. Str contains the filename, and the code changes it if needed, leaves it alone otherwise.

`int second = -1`;

```
 int first = str.indexOf(".");
   if (first>-1){
        second = str.indexOf(".", first + 1);
   }
   if (second>-1){
       str=str.substring(0, second);
   }
```

adapted from: [Finding second occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035893/finding-second-occurrence-of-a-substring-in-a-string-in-java)