# How to split a string after the nth occurence of a character?

Tags: javascript, split

I have a string which i need to split in javascript 
var str = 'Lenovo Essential G500s (59-388254) Laptop (3rd Gen Ci5/ 8GB/ 1TB/ DOS/ 2GB Graph) (Free carry bag) (Black)';

I need to retrieve just 'Lenovo Essential G500s (59-388254) Laptop'
i.e, i should be able to split the string after the second occurrence of '(' character.

I have tried using the .split() function, but I am not able to specify the position.
Please help.

Answer (score 4):

```
  var str = 'Lenovo Essential G500s (59-388254) Laptop (3rd Gen Ci5/ 8GB/ 1TB/ DOS/ 2GB Graph) (Free carry bag) (Black)';

  var firstBracket = str.indexOf('(');
  var secondBracket = str.indexOf('(', firstBracket+1)
  str.substring(0, secondBracket);
```

This will give you the section you're looking for.

For a more general solution, see the existing answer: [How to get the nth occurrence in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480345/how-to-get-the-nth-occurrence-in-a-string)

Comment: OP is asking for the nth occurrence. This only fits one example in which n=1 (assuming zero-based index).

Comment: He asks for "second occurrence of '(' character". I cannot see a question for the nth occurrence.

Comment: I'll add the existing question which a quick Google revealed.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var str = 'Lenovo Essential G500s (59-388254) Laptop (3rd Gen Ci5/ 8GB/ 1TB/ DOS/ 2GB Graph) (Free carry bag) (Black)';

var index =  str.indexOf(")");

var res = str.substring(0, index +1);

alert(res);
```

Cheers