# How to dynamically split a string using JavaScript/jQuery after so many occurences of a character

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, split

I'm looking for a way to split a string in JavaScript dynamically and keep the contents after so many occurrences of a particular character. I've tried searching all over for something to solve this, though not had any success. Here's an example of the format I'll be using:

`var s = "17:44, 22 July 2015 Foo connected to chat from address 127.0.0.1";`

In the above example, I want the rest of the contents of the line after 2015, though at the same time I don't want to use 2015 or any of the start of the string as a hardcoded way to split because users can call themselves that, which would mess up the way of splitting, as well as I sometimes have to go back years too.

In a nutshell I want to split the string after the 4th space dynamically, and keep whatever is after without splitting the rest too.

Comment: [How to split a string after the nth occurence of a character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293872/how-to-split-a-string-after-the-nth-occurence-of-a-character)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do matching instead of splitting.

```
> var s = "17:44, 22 July 2015 Foo connected to chat from address 127.0.0.1";
> s.match(/^((?:\S+\s+){3}\S+)\s+(.+)/)
[ '17:44, 22 July 2015 Foo connected to chat from address 127.0.0.1',
  '17:44, 22 July 2015',
  'Foo connected to chat from address 127.0.0.1',
  index: 0,
  input: '17:44, 22 July 2015 Foo connected to chat from address 127.0.0.1' ]
> s.match(/^((?:\S+\s+){3}\S+)\s+(.+)/)[1]
'17:44, 22 July 2015'
> s.match(/^((?:\S+\s+){3}\S+)\s+(.+)/)[2]
'Foo connected to chat from address 127.0.0.1'
```

**OR**

```js
var s = "17:44, 22 July 2015 Foo connected to chat from address 127.0.0.1";
alert(s.match(/^(?:\S+\s+){3}\S+|\S.*/g))
```

- `^(?:\S+\s+){3}\S+` would match the first four words.
- `|` OR
- `\S` matches the first non-space character from the remaining string.
- `.*` greedily matches all the remaining characters.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and examples, very useful, did exactly what I wanted :)

Comment: What if I want to keep the date as a single split? The Output I need is `"17:44 22 July 2015, Foo connected to chat from address 127.0.0.1"`

Answer (score 1):

[Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) for resovle issue

```js
function splitter(string, character, occurrences) {
  var tmparr = string.split(character); // split string by passed character, it returns Array
  return tmparr.slice(occurrences, tmparr.length).join(" "); // slice returns a shallow copy of a portion of an Array into a new Array object. And finally join() - joins all elements of an array into a string.
}

var s = "17:44, 22 July 2015 Foo connected to chat from address 127.0.0.1";

alert(splitter(s, ' ', 4))
```

Comment: can you add some explanation?