# How can I convert a twitter user ID into a user name in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter

I have a twiter web app that I am building. It is following a select group of twitter IDs and only picking out tweets that they post based on again a select group of keywords. Everything is working fine except I want to convert the twitter ID i have in an array into the corresponding twitter user name (one by one) so for example the array of IDs is var trackedHandles; and i want to convert trackedHandles[i] to a user name and print it the console next to the actual tweet. SO it would look like this in the console: @me: here is my tweet Here is my code selection that relates to this:

```
t.stream(
    "statuses/filter",
    {track: trackedHandles + trackedWords, lang: "en" },
    function(stream) {
        stream.on('data', function(tweet) {
            for (var i= 0; i < trackedData.length; i++) {
                if(tweet.text.indexOf(trackedData[i]) > - 1) {
                    // incriments added value to the word
                    redisClient.incr(trackedData[i]);

                    console.log(trackedHandles[i] + ":" + " " + tweet.text + " " );
                    //console.log(trackedData[i]);
                }
            }
        }); 
    }
);
```

Right now i'm just printing the twitter ID, but again I want to print the username. I appreciate your help.

Comment: What is currently being outputted in the console?

Comment: the user id: plus tweet so 12344556: here is my tweet

Comment: What kind of REST response are you receiving in your stream? Can you give us the Resource URL that you're hitting to receive the data?

Comment: not sure, but I am using ntwitter, express and nodejs. I created a developer account with twitter and I have my credentials in a .js file as well. I am just not sure how to convert the ids into usernames

Comment: So are you saying that the only 2 pieces of data you're receiving is the user ID and the tweet text? Try logging "tweet" in the stream.on() callback. If the screen_name doesn't show up there, I'm really not sure. Most of twitter's GET calls that return tweets seems to include both the userid and the screen_name

Comment: tweet.text only prints the tweet no user ID or no screen name, But trackedHandles[i]  prints the user ID and I want to take that var and convert it to the screen name

Comment: The whole purpose of this so when I present my app in for my senior project I can show them the tweets are appearing the app is working but further more it will be clear who tweeted the tweet since screen names are more identifiable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out on my own! In case someone in the future needs to know how though:

```
        //Get Screen_Name from tweet object.
        function getPosition(str,m, i) { //special helper function to find the nth position of a string.
            return str.split(m, i).join(m).length;
        }
        var snStartingPos = getPosition(tweetObject, "screen_name", 2); //starting position of "screen_name" in tweet object.
        var snEndingPos = snStartingPos + 14; //ending position of "screen_name" in tweet object (where we actually want to start).
        var unStartingPos = getPosition(tweetObject, "location", 1); //starting position of the word after where we want to end.
        var unPrePos = unStartingPos - 3; //subtract that by 3 characters to exclude the unnecessary characters
        var snLength = unPrePos - snEndingPos; //this is now the length of the screen_name we want
        var screen_name = "@" + tweetObject.substr(snEndingPos, snLength); //get the sub-str that we want (the "screen_name") from tweet object.
        //End Get Screen_Name from tweet Object
```

tweetObject is just tweet converted as a string. the function getPosition, I got off another stackOverflow question page: [How to get the nth occurrence in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480345/how-to-get-the-nth-occurrence-in-a-string)