# How do I fix the time difference between MomentJS and Asp.net Core

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-core

I have a date that is set in my UI from this angularjs [date picker](https://github.com/g00fy-/angular-datepicker).  It is set as a moment.js object and it includes a GMT offset for my timezone (Eastern).  When I submit the moment object back to my Asp.net Core endpoint, the time is converted to the time with no offset.  So for example, when I inspect date in the javascript moment object object:

```
timeIn: Fri Dec 16 2016 05:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

And when I inspect my object in .net core:

```
TimeIn: 12/16/2016 10:00:00AM
```

I want the data on the back end to show as the exact time entered on the UI, regardless of timezone.  So if they enter 5:00AM, the time backend should store is 5:00AM.  It appears to change the value when the moment object is converted to JSON to send to the backend.  When I do a JSON.stringify() of my timeIn object on the UI, I get:

```
"2016-12-16T10:00:00.000Z"
```

Is there a way to strip the offset data from the timezone on the front end so that the time entered is the exact same as the time sent?

P.S. I know there are a lot of questions out there about time but I wasn't able to find a suitable one for my case.  Thanks for your help

**EDIT:** I am using .net DateTime object to accept the javascript date object.

Comment: If you switch to a DateTimeOffset your life will become easier.

Comment: I believe DateTimeOffset identifies a single point in time so it will take timezones into account.  For example, if a user enters timeIn of 5am and they are in the pacific timezone, and then a supervisor in the eastern timezone looks at that time entry, my app *should* show 5am to the supervisor, not 8am.  I need the time entered to show the same to any user, regardless of the timezone they are in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This format contains 5 spaces:

```
Fri Dec 16 2016 05:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

And we can assume `20` to be a minimum, safe entry for landing in the year. Get the next occurrence of space character and split from there.

> **Note:** This one is totally based on assumptions, but it looks like it works better.

You can do something like:

```js
var time = "Fri Dec 16 2016 05:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)";
console.log(time.substr(0, time.indexOf(" ", 20)));
```

Also, with reference to [How to get the nth occurrence in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480345/how-to-get-the-nth-occurrence-in-a-string), we can achieve something better.

```
function getPosition(string, subString, index) {
   return string.split(subString, index).join(subString).length;
}
```

We need the 5th occurrence of the space:

```js
function getPosition(string, subString, index) {
   return string.split(subString, index).join(subString).length;
}
var time = "Fri Dec 16 2016 05:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)";
console.log(time.substr(0, getPosition(time, " ", 5)));
```

The second method seems to be a better one than the first.

The third method is to use the Moment.js library to format the time into a format accepted by .Net:

```
timeIn = timeIn.format('MM-DD-YYYY h:mm:ss');
```

Comment: Looks like that does work.  I found another way to do it using the moment.js library.  timeIn = timeIn.format('MM-DD-YYYY h:mm:ss'); This format is accepted by .net and comes in properly as well.

Comment: @big_water Awesome... `:D` Do you wanna add that into my answer and accept it? Your wish... `:)`

Comment: I will do so!  Although I don't think the moment.js library will run in a snippet, unless you know of a way?

Comment: @big_water It runs mate. Okay, I'll add it myself then.

Comment: No offense, but are you complete nuts to post such a solution? This is just plain wrong. The time sent to the server is the correct date, it's the UTC representation of `Fri Dec 16 2016 05:00:00 GMT-0500`, which is absolut correct. What you effectively did is, to cut off the timezone and the time send to the server is effectively 5 hours off (in this case) from the real time, which will completely mess off the dates. A person who posts something at 5:00 GMT-5 will appear "before" someone who post at 8:00 GMT -1, even though "8:00 GMT -1" is clearly 1 hour earlier than "5:00 GMT-5".

Comment: This will completely screw the sorting and filtering by time, so if you don't understand UTC time, don't post anything on it.

Comment: @Tseng You are absolutely right. This is for a localised application and I have spoken with the OP. So nothing to worry. `:)`