# Get the index of the nth occurrence in a string

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a function that returns the index of a specific occurrence of a specific character from a string. However, I can only get it to successfully return the 1st or 2nd index. My function is as follows:

```
function getIndex(str,char,n) {
    return str.indexOf(char, str.indexOf(char) + n-1);
}
```

Entering these tests only works for the first 2:

```
getIndex('https://www.example.example2.co.uk','.',2) // successfully returns 19
getIndex('https://www.example.example2.co.uk','.',1) // successfully returns 11
getIndex('https://www.example.example2.co.uk','.',3) // unsuccessfully returns 19
```

Does anyone have any ideas about how this could work for more than 2 instances? An example of how I'm using it would be to get the following:

```
var str = 'https://www.example.example2.co.uk';
str.substring(31); // returns .uk
str.substring(28, 31); // returns .co
```

Thanks for any help here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the nth occurrence in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480345/how-to-get-the-nth-occurrence-in-a-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `split`, `slice` & `join` to achieve your requirement.

**Logic**

First `split` your string with `char` then use `slice` to join split values upto `nth` occurrence. Then simply join with `char`. It's `length` will be your answer.

Check below.

```js
function getIndex(str, char, n) {
  return str.split(char).slice(0, n).join(char).length;
}

console.log(getIndex('https://www.example.example2.co.uk', '.', 2)) // returns 19
console.log(getIndex('https://www.example.example2.co.uk', '.', 1)) // returns 11
console.log(getIndex('https://www.example.example2.co.uk', '.', 3)) // returns 28
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you are not specifying nth occurance

```
str.indexOf(char, str.indexOf(char) + n-1);
```

Here you are trying to skip `str.indexOf(char) + n-1` characters and continue the search
Try this function

```
function getIndex(str,char,n) {
    return str.split('')
            .map((ch,index)=>ch===char?index:-1)
            .filter(in=>in!=-1)[n-1];
}
```

- Say string is `Hello` and you are looking for 2nd l
- Split the string into characters [H,e,l,l,0]
- map them to index if it is the character you are looking for
  [-1,-1,2,3,-1]
- Filter all -1 [2,3]
- Take the 2nd index using n-1 that is 3

Answer (score 2):

```
const search = '.';
const indexOfAll = (arr, val) => arr.reduce((acc, curr, i) => (curr === val ? [...acc, i] : acc), []);

indexOfAll(Array.from('https://www.example.example2.co.uk'), search);
=> [ 11, 19, 28, 31 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function findIndex(str, searchCharacter, n){
    var length = str.length, i= -1;
    while(n-- && i++<length ){
        i= str.indexOf(searchCharacter, i);
        if (i < 0) break;
    }
    return i;
}     

var index = findIndex('https://www.example.example2.co.uk','.',3);
console.log(index);
////
//  28
////
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the fastest solution

```
function getIndex(str, character, n) {
    return str.split(character, n).join(character).length;
}

var v1 = getIndex("https://www.example.example2.co.uk", ".", 1);
var v2 = getIndex("https://www.example.example2.co.uk", ".", 2);
var v3 = getIndex("https://www.example.example2.co.uk", ".", 3);
var v4 = getIndex("https://www.example.example2.co.uk", ".", 4);
var v5 = getIndex("https://www.example.example2.co.uk", ".", 5);

console.log(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the regex [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) method:

```js
function getIndex(str, find, occ) {
  var regex = new RegExp(`\\${find}`, 'g');
  let arr, count = 0;
  while ((arr = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (++count == occ) return regex.lastIndex - 1; 
  }
}

const a = getIndex('https://www.example.example2.co.uk','.',2);
const b = getIndex('https://www.example.example2.co.uk','.',1);
const c = getIndex('https://www.example.example2.co.uk','.',3);

console.log(a, b, c);
```