# How to remove everyting after second occurrence of a specific character?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string like below

```
var str = "Lorem Ipsum is simply& dummy text of the &printing and & typesetting industry."
```

How can I remove the second character `&` and everything after it in jQuery?

Comment: There are a few different ways. What direction are you going in, and what have you tried?

Comment: This Stackoverflow question may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480345/how-to-get-the-nth-occurrence-in-a-string

Comment: You want something like `str.split("&", 2).join("&")`? NB: this has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: Thanks trincot this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can combine `split` and `join`:

```
str.split("&", 2).join("&")
```

The argument `2` will make that `split` only returns the first two substrings that are split off, the rest is ignored. `join` would put those 2 pieces back together with the restored `&`.