# getting first two parts of an string separated by - sign

Tags: javascript

Is there an easier way to do this:

```js
    let layer_id = "55-16-A1"
    
    console.log(layer_id.split("-").slice(0,2).join("-"));
// I want: 55-16
```

I want to get first two parts of id but I only can do it by doing three methods on it which is not an elegant way I think... is there any better way to do this?

Comment: I don't think you're going to get anything simpler and more elegant than what you've already got. It seems fine to me.

Comment: Remember that *clear* code is, often, better than *clever* code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  layer_id.slice(0, layer_id.lastIndexOf("-")) // take the part till the last -
  // or, depending on the exact usecase
  layer_id.slice(0, layer_id.indexOf("-", layer_id.indexOf("-"))) // take the string till the second -
  // or
  layer_id.match(/(\d+-\d+)/)[0] // take the first part that matches two groups of one or more chars seperated by a -
  // or
  layer_id.slice(0, 5) // take only the first 5 chars
```

A bit shorter and possibly slightly more efficient. Not necessarily easier to understand.

Comment: There's also `layer_id.match(/(\d+-\d+)/)[0];` if you wanted to add that as well for completion?

Comment: You're very welcome, it didn't seem worth adding another answer to 'compete' for votes/acceptance, and wrong to just edit it into your answer without your consent. I would suggest that explain your code, though. That way OP and future visitors can learn, and understand what's going on :)

Comment: @david yup, would've done the same. Also added an explanation (a brief one, but I think it covers everything necessary)

Answer (score 4):

You could take the *limit* parameter of [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and get only the first two elements from splitting.

```js
let layer_id = "55-16-A1"

console.log(layer_id.split("-", 2).join("-")); // 55-16
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the split in one step via the substring method but you need the index.  If you definitely need the split at the second occurrence of "-" see [How to get the nth occurrence in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480345/how-to-get-the-nth-occurrence-in-a-string)

Otherwise if you are OK with split at the last occurrence:

```
console.log(layer_id.substring(0, layer_id.lastIndexOf("-"));
```